# php upload - undefined index iis

Tags: php, html, iis, upload, undefined-index

My html form looks something like this:

```
 <form action="dins.php" method="get" name="test" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table class="formTable" id="programTable">
            <tr>
                <td class="ft_head">Title</td>
                <td><input type="text" size="26px" name="title" id="title" autocomplete="off" /></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="ft_head">Objective</td>
                <td><textarea width="26px" height="18px" name="obj" id="obj" autocomplete="off"></textarea></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="ft_head">Theory</td>
                <td><textarea width="26px" height="36px" name="theory" id="theory" autocomplete="off"></textarea></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="ft_head">Code</td>
                <td><input type="file" width="26px" name="code" id="code" /></textarea></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="ft_head">Output</td>
                <td><input type="file" width="26px" name="output" id="output" /></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="ft_head">Conclusion</td>
                <td><textarea width="26px" height="36px"          name="conc" id="conc" autocomplete="off"></textarea></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="sub" /> 
    <form>
```

My part php script is this:

```
if(isset($_GET['title']) && isset($_GET['obj']) && isset($_GET['theory']) &&   
$_FILES['code']['size']>0 && $_FILES['output']['size']>0 && isset($_GET['conc']))
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 _Unable to fetch values.PHP Notice: Undefined index: code in    
 E:\Repository\HTML\123\assign_cg\dins.php on line 4_
```

I tried modifying php.ini for `upload_max_size` but did not help. I am running `WIMP.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should change your form method to POST.**

You cannot upload files via `GET`, that is what `POST` is for.

In case more clarification is really needed, `GET` is generally used for *retrieving* data from the server, while `POST` is for *sending* data to the server.

Comment: But we do generally use GET to send data to the server, especially with ajax, so I thought may be I could do the same with files.

Comment: @check Of course, with every request, regardless of type, data is being transmitted to the server. Wether to use GET or POST largely depends on the result you want to get: POST is used for sending data to the server and not necessarily expecting a response. GET is used for sending a request to the server in expectation of a response to the request.